# OpenGL Rendering Modes

Tags: opengl

So far I know about immediate, display list, vertex buffer and vertex buffer object rendering. Which is the fastest? Which OpenGL version does each require? What should I use?

Comment: "*vertex buffer and vertex buffer object rendering*" Those two are the same thing. Also, this question cannot be answered; the answer will be hardware-specific, driver version specific, and *workload* specific.

Answer (score 5):

The best (and pretty much only) method of rendering now is to use general purpose buffers, AKA Vertex Buffer Objects. They are in core from 2.1, if I'm correct, but generally appeared as an extension in **1.5** (as `ARB_vertex_buffer_object`). They have hardware support, which means they can be and probably will be stored directly in GPU memory.

When you load data to them, you specify the suggested usage. You can read more about it in [glBufferData](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBufferData.xml) manual. For example, `GL_STATIC_DRAW` is something very similar to static display list. This allows your graphics card to optimize access to them.

Answer (score 3):

Modern (read: non-ancient) hardware really dislikes immediate mode. I've seen a nearly 2-order-of-magnitude performance improvement by replacing immediate mode with vertex arrays.

OpenGL 3 and above support only buffer objects, all other rendering modes are deprecated.

Display lists are a serious pain to use correctly, and not worth it on non-ancient hardware.

To summarize: if you use OpenGL 3+, you have to use (V)BOs. If you target OpenGL 2, use vertex arrays or VBOs as appropriate.